# Create a Mapbox Point

Tags: android, mapbox

I am trying to instantiate a Point object from `Mapbox`, **Android SDK** but it seems not to have a constructor. Please help.

```
Point point;
point = new Point();
```

Can I create a Point from `LatLong` coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the most basic way to create a `Point`

```
Point point = Point.fromLngLat()
```

Comment: Thank you. And what about instanciating new Location?

Comment: Cool, glad I could help.
Regarding location...What are you trying to achieve? To show the device's location on the map? If so, check out https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/plugins/overview/location-layer/ , https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/tree/master/plugin-locationlayer, and https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/plugins/LocationPluginActivity.java